# Bulk deleting an array of messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have this command that deletes x amount of  messages sent by a bot in the last 50 messages. The code for it was something along the lines of this (I already deleted it to try and fix this issue myself so this is just something that would have been close):

```
@client.command(aliases=['bc'])
async def BotClean(ctx, count=5):
    messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=50).flatten()
    for message in messages:
        if (message.author.bot):
            ctx.channel.purge(message)
```

but I didn't like how the messages got deleted one by one.

In order to try and get around this instead of purging the messages I added them to an array and I thought I remembered seeing a bulk delete command in the docs but I couldn't find it when I looked for it again, so is there any way for me to bulk delete an array of messages or something similar that will fix the messages being deleted one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`discord.TextChannel.purge()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.TextChannel.purge) has a `check` parameter that you can use for this. In fact, deleting bot's messages is the example given in the method's documentation:

```py
def is_me(m):
    return m.author == client.user

deleted = await channel.purge(limit=100, check=is_me)
await channel.send('Deleted {} message(s)'.format(len(deleted)))
```

As for bulk deleting, there's a `bulk` parameter that you can set to `True`:

```py
await channel.purge(limit=100, bulk=True)
```

In order to bulk delete, your bot will need the `manage_messages` permission. If it doesn't have it, it will go back to single delete.

PS: I'm not sure about it, but you could try using `lambda` functions for your check:

```py
deleted = await channel.purge(limit=100, check=lambda m: m.author==client.user)
await channel.send('Deleted {} message(s)'.format(len(deleted)))
```